# C# Console Calculator about if statement

Tags: c#, console-application, calculator

I have no idea know what's wrong with my if statement.
The program just switch off after  Asked the user to enter their gender.
Enter 1 If you are Male
Enter 2 If you are Female

```
        static void Main(string[] args) {

        int WaistToHeightCalculatorOption,GenderOption;

        double HeightCm = 0.0, WaistCm = 0.0; 
        double WaistToHeightRatio = 0.0;
        string WaistToHeightCalculatorMenu = ("Which Measurement You Want to use to enter the weight and height?"
                                           + "\n1)Enter 1 for Metric"
                                           + "\n2)Enter 2 for British Imperial:");
        Console.Write(WaistToHeightCalculatorMenu);
        WaistToHeightCalculatorOption = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

        if (WaistToHeightCalculatorOption == 1) {
            Console.Write("\nPlease Enter your Height in cm:");
            HeightCm = double.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
            Console.Write("\nPlease Enter your Waist in centimetres (cm):");
            WaistCm = double.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
            WaistToHeightRatio = WaistCm / HeightCm;
            Console.WriteLine("Your Waist to Height Ratio is {0}", WaistToHeightRatio);

            Console.Write("\n1)Enter 1 If you are Male"
                        + "\n2)Enter 2 If you are Female:");
            GenderOption = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

            if (GenderOption ==1) {
                if (WaistToHeightRatio >= 0.536) {
                    Console.WriteLine("Your Risk of Obesity Related Cardiovascular Diseases is at High Risk");
                } else if (WaistToHeightRatio < 0.536) {
                    Console.WriteLine("Your Risk of Obesity Related Cardiovascular Diseases is at low Risk");
                }
            } else if (GenderOption == 2) {
                if (WaistToHeightRatio >= 0.492) {
                    Console.Write("Your Risk of Obesity Related Cardiovascular Diseases is at High Risk");
                } else if (WaistToHeightRatio < 0.492) {
                    Console.Write("Your Risk of Obesity Related Cardiovascular Diseases is at low Risk");
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: Does it stop before you enter a value, or after?  Maybe you could post the entire output of interacting with your program.

Comment: you need to add `Console.Read();`, before you exit main program

Comment: WaistToHeightCalculatorOption == 1 , string comparision with integer, have a look at it

Comment: add Console.ReadKey(); after your else if(GenderOption == 2){ } statement.

Comment: The suggestions to add Console.Read() or Console.ReadKey() are making the assumption that you're running this from Visual Studio. I agree with that assumption as well.  You can also open the Command Prompt and run the compiled program from the command-line.  This would result in the console window not closing when the program finishes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just press Ctr + F5 in Visual Studio or add `Console.ReadKey();` at the end to wait for user to enter any key before exit the program.

Answer (score 1):

Because after the last input , you just print to screen and exit the program.

Also your indentation can be confusing, I think this way is more readable.

what happens if gender is not 1 or 2 ? you should let the user know that he make a mistake , or loop till you get what you want (1 or 2)

```
        if (GenderOption ==1){
            if (WaistToHeightRatio >= 0.536) {
                Console.WriteLine("Your Risk of Obesity Related Cardiovascular Diseases is at High Risk");
            } 
            else {
                Console.WriteLine("Your Risk of Obesity Related Cardiovascular Diseases is at low Risk");
            }
        } 
        else 
            if (GenderOption == 2) {
                if (WaistToHeightRatio >= 0.492) {
                    Console.Write("Your Risk of Obesity Related Cardiovascular Diseases is at High Risk");
                } 
                else {
                    Console.Write("Your Risk of Obesity Related Cardiovascular Diseases is at low Risk");
                }
            }
```